# Finding the radius of incircle of $\triangle ABC$ where each of three other circles is mutually tangent to two sides of the triangle respectively

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

> In acute angled $\triangle ABC$, considering a portion of side $BC$ as diameter, a circle is drawn whose radius is 18 units and it touches two sides $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Similarly, considering a portion of sides $AC$ and $AB$ as diameters, two other circles are drawn whose radii are $6$ and $9$ units respectively. What is the radius of the incircle of $\triangle ABC$?

[image]

Consider the diagram above. Here, $FL = 18, EI = 6$ and $DK = 9$ and yellow marked circle is the incircle.

I couldn't find a way out to determine each side of the triangle $ABC$. I researched with the diagram in *Geogebra* for a while, connecting or drawing some important segments but nothing seemed to me so much effective or useful.

**Is there any formula by which I can get directly the radius of incircle with the given condition?** Thanks in advance.

**SOURCE**: Bangladesh Math Olympiad

Comment: This question was previously asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078717/three-circles-having-centres-on-the-three-sides-of-a-triangle/3134423#3134423). I have added a new answer there, to cover an issue that the old answers didn't.